# Why does my Mock fetch always returns null? (Jest)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, mocking

I have a simple React component that is calling a local API to get a list of products on component mount. The functionality itself works fine. The app is created by create-react-app.
However, I'm also trying to test the fetch function in Jest but my mocked global fetch always returns null. Does anyone have an idea why?

It's like my mocked function never even gets called or isn't in scope of the component logic? However the original global fetch doesn't get called either. Just null is returned.

I've also tried re-writing my fetch to use a .then() follow-up and I've tried using the jest-fetch-mock package but the results are the same. I can call my (real) fetch function from the tests and it returns correctly. Only the mocked fetch is causing problems.

Here is the tutorial I've been following:
https://www.leighhalliday.com/mock-fetch-jest

The component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Product from './Product';

import './Shop.css';


export async function fetchProducts() {
    try {
        const result = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/products', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
        const data = await result.json();
        return data;
    } catch (e) {
        return null;
    } 
}

function Shop() {

    const [products, setProducts] = useState([])

    useEffect(async () => {
        const result = await fetchProducts();
        setProducts(result);
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <h2>Shop</h2>
            <ul className='list-reset products-wrapper'>
                {products.map((product) => (
                    <Product
                        key={product.id}
                        {...product} />
                ))}
            </ul>
        </>
    );
}

export default Shop;
```

The test:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import Shop, { fetchProducts } from './Shop';

// Mocking the fetch function
global.fetch = jest.fn(() => {
    return Promise.resolve({
        json: () => Promise.resolve([
            {
                id: '1',
                productName: 'Banana',
                price: 0.39,
                image: ''
            }
        ])
    })
});

beforeEach(() => {
    fetch.mockClear();
});

test('requests the products on mount', async () => {
    const products = await fetchProducts();
    expect(products).toEqual({
        id: '1',
        productName: 'Banana',
        price: 0.39,
        image: ''
    })
});
```

Failing test:

```
 FAIL  src/components/Shop/Shop.test.js
  ● requests the products on mount

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: {"id": "1", "image": "", "price": 0.39, "productName": "Banana"}
    Received: null
```

If I log out the mocked `fetch` method as the test is running it logs the Jest mock:

```
[Function: mockConstructor] {
        _isMockFunction: true,
        getMockImplementation: [Function],
        mock: [Getter/Setter],
        mockClear: [Function],
        mockReset: [Function],
        mockRestore: [Function],
        mockReturnValueOnce: [Function],
        mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function],
        mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function],
        mockReturnValue: [Function],
        mockResolvedValue: [Function],
        mockRejectedValue: [Function],
        mockImplementationOnce: [Function],
        mockImplementation: [Function],
        mockReturnThis: [Function],
        mockName: [Function],
        getMockName: [Function]
      }
```

Comment: I've gotten this to work by using `global.fetch = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve({//stuff}))` though I'm not entirely sure what the difference is

Comment: Is ///stuff there the returned object?
It is also returning null

Comment: `//stuff` in this case would be `json: () => Promise.resolve([//return values]}`

basically just change `jest.fn(()=>)` to `jest.fn().mockReturnValue()`

Comment: `global.fetch = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve({
    json: () => Promise.resolve([
        {
            id: '1',
            productName: 'Banana',
            price: 0.39,
            image: ''
        }
    ])
}))`
also returns null but thanks for the advice

Comment: Well in that case I'd try changing your catch statement to log a message and see what the error it is catching is

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined
`result` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

It is missing the following config from `package.json`:

```
  "jest": {
    "resetMocks": false
  }
```

Comment: "resetMocks": false is the default - so unless it's been added it will not need to be set false. I understand that there is / was a conflict between jest-fetch-mock (it uses mocks internally which are reset if resetMocks is set true globally.

Answer (score -1):

To make the call work, trigger it like this:

```
useEffect((async () => {
  const result = await fetchProducts();
  setProducts(result);
})(), []);
```

I've basically wrapped the async in an [IIFE](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiy4YeS_rrxAhX3zTgGHWVjBMoQFjAFegQIBRAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FGlossary%2FIIFE&usg=AOvVaw1CP0sdxqWSRo3rxvRMR2HZ).

**Why is this required ?**

`useEffect` expects a cleanup function as callback. In your example, `async () =>` this async written inside `useEffect` returns a promise (like all async functions) and therefore it does not get triggered as your requirement.

Comment: This has an unexpected token. Also the question is about testing the fetchProducts function in isolation.